# JSF 2.1 + RichFaces 4 - Paging dataGrid

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, richfaces

I have `List<Product> products` in my backEnd Bean which contains about 70 items.

I need to show it as 3 X 4 table with option to navigate between pages "next", "Previous" and option to click on page number.

How can it be done? I have no problem to use Datagrid, but how to combine it with paging?

**Update:**
I did the following:

```
  <h:form>
        <rich:dataGrid value="#{productBean.products}" var="product" columns="4" id="productsList">
      <h:outputText value="#{product.sku}"/>
<f:facet name="footer">       
    </f:facet>
    </rich:dataGrid>
<rich:dataScroller for="productsList" maxPages="10"/>
   </h:form>
```

but my problem is that now I have a table with 4 columns and 18 rows. 
how Can change it to 3 rows per page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `<rich:dataScroller>` in any of the `<f:facet>` of the `<rich:dataGrid>` .

For example:

```
<rich:dataGrid>
        ........................
        ........................
    <f:facet name="footer">
        <rich:dataScroller/>
    </f:facet>
</rich:dataGrid>
```

Then , the paging control is at the bottom of the data grid.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the real tag looks like this:

```
<rich:dataScroller />
```

(Big S, if someone copy paste the previous example will get error!)

Comment: Next time better improve the answer instead of posting another answer which basically answers the same.

Comment: Sorry i just thought that i haven't enough reputation to do that